# Using an Android phone like a SIP ATA

Tags: voip, sip

I would like to get a few Android phones functioning as a SIP ATA so I can make and receive calls via SIP. I realize one could use Bluetooth to pair with something like Asterisk, but I had high hopes there might be a standalone application that would transform it into an ATA. Is there something out that that will allow me to do this?

Edit: Yep, searched Play Store nothing to be found unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

**There is a SIP client built right into your phone** (Gingerbread and above). You can find this either in general settings, or in settings for the phone dialer app.

E.g. in Jellybean:

- go to the phone dialer page (as if you were going to make a call)
- choose the menu (bottom right vertical "...")
- tap Settings
- Scroll down to "Accounts" and tap it.
- enter your SIP account info.

Simple as that!

Depending on what SIP service you're connecting to, you may find yourself in the world of codecs. The built-in dialer will try to use the following codecs:

1. GSM-EFR
2. AMR
3. GSM
4. G711u
5. G711a

If you're using regular an Asterisk-based SIP server, then it will mostly likely end up using G711 (aka ULAW). I'm still experimenting, but so far I've had more luck with GSM and was able to tweak my Asterisk server to use that instead. If you're using a 3rd party service, then chances are they've enabled GSM already.

That said, I did use [CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple) to get as far as I did. It allows easy selection of which codecs will be used when (WiFi vs 3/4G), so it made debugging much simpler. (Btw, their store version is quite old at the time I'm writing this. You can also download daily builds and try those.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I'm seeking a way to dial out from the device as well as redirect inbound calls to Asterisk right from the phone. As far as I can tell the SIP apps and tools I see now only allow you to dial out from the device and receive calls sent to it.

Comment: Ah, so you want to enable the following scenario: call comes into your phone over the cell network, gets forwarded by the phone to a SIP connection back to an existing SIP server, e.g. the Asterisk Box back at the office. Is that it?

Comment: mm2001, you got it! That's exactly it. The idea being while in the office it's far better to have the PBX take over the cellular connections so all calls are answered and handled as they should be.

Comment: Ok, so now I understand - and also understand why its tricky. I don't know enough about the underlying APIs to know if its even possible without rooting the phone. Like the bluetooth support you mention elsewhere, it opens up the carriers to "abuse" by leveraging in-network calls and similar. I'm guessing the alternative of porting the cell phone numbers to VOIP and having them forward from the PBX to the cell network is out of the question because these are personal cell phone numbers? It could perhaps have the same effect but with more hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You will find nothing as it is not possible, Even you can make / answer calls programmatically but you can't control Voice / media flow due to some restrictions in Android Radio Interface Layer (RIL). for media/voice you have to relay on some other interfaces like Mic / speaker, Bluetooth, hand-free or loopback wires but all these thing are not what you are looking for! So in short you can't use it as GSM Gateway or VoIP ATA.

If you want to read more then please visit [Why it is not possible to use Android as VoIP ATA](http://www.ictinnovations.com/using-android-phone-as-gsm-gateway)

Comment: My Samsung phone has a call on text on other devices feature. This is able to forward GSM voice calls over internet. So some Samsung app is already able to intercept incoming and outgoing audio.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use android handsets as a SIP phone.

There's not even a requirement for a call/data plan, you don't need a SIM inserted for it to work.

Search for [SIP](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=SIP&c=apps) on Google Play and you'll find some:

- [CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple)
- [Sipdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua)

To clarify: You most probably mixed something up, a SIP ATA is an *analog telephone adapter*, a device that speaks SIP on the one an POTS on the other side and converts an old telephone into a SIP phone. Android phones won't do that, they are a handset on their own and have no POTS interface. Bluetooth will also not help you to connect to Asterisk. Asterisk is a SIP server and does not allow Android handsets to pair via bluetooth for calls (that's solely for using bluetooth enabled phones as FX0/FXS channels for faxing/making calls).

Comment: Nothing was mixed up. The POTS side of business would be the mobile network. Also, Asterisk does most certainly support pairing with bluetooth devices to achieve similar goals to what I speak of and has since (at least) v1.4. See chan_mobile for more details. I am seeking a similar software solution to what might be more commonly known as more of a bluetooth SIP gateway.

Comment: Er, ok. Now I understand what you want to achieve. This wasn't clear from a first look at the question to me. Seems like my answer is off topic to your question. Good question though, it's however a little localized and I'm not sure if so. can answer it here. Seems more dev related (I don't know an out-of-the box solution ad-hoc, you might better ask also on asterisk's mailing list also). Could you edit your answer accordingly to maybe include a 'user story' for that to reflect your problem better?

Comment: Seems like someone also wants this: http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Android-Asterisk-PBX/Android-SIP-IAX-GSM-Asterisk.html

Comment: Well that's pretty much what I was thinking ce4. It's not the most ideal solution but it would be great for those who want to bind our cellular devices with office systems during work hours, and still use them on call while outside the office. I'll keep my fingers crossed, but so far I haven't been able to find anything suitable. :) Seems chan_mobile it might be!

Answer (score 0):

I would just call forward (*72XXXXXXXXXX) the cell phone to the desired SIP DID number. Boom, all calls re-routed.

Comment: Was trying to do the opposite...